# What is the difference between 'try' and 'attempt' when used as nouns?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

Why is it possible to say

> The speech is an attempt to pacify all parties concerned.

but not *"The speech is a try to ...."

Although they are interchangeable in

> I will give it another try/attempt
>
> It was a good try/attempt

Comment: Why is this driving you nuts? The same is true of *any* two words. Sometimes you can swap, other times you can't. Synonyms only exist in context. The two words are used differently because they are *different* words. If they were exactly the same, one of them wouldn't exist.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: ok, but there is A REASON for the use of one or the other! Say as I say, write as I write is definitely NOT an explanation. There is hope, even for people who were not born and bred in an English-speaking country! See my answer… it's the condescension of too many native speakers of English that drives (some) foreigners nuts, not English itself!

Comment: Saying you "attempted and failed" puts a much better spin on your failure than does "tried and failed".

Comment: @Naomi: a language is not just usage! Keep trying… to answer your students' questions!

Comment: @user58319 I've read your answer and it says nothing at all about a reason, much less "A REASON". All it says is what these words mean now. (By quoting dictionary definitions, no less, which always *follow* usage.) Stating the current status quo does not equal to explaining how it came about. And yeah, the *reason* for the words being used that way is indeed "say as I say, write as I write". As to the rest of your comment, I have no idea who in this exchange you think is condescending, and who a native speaker, but I get that weird vibe you are plain wrong on both accounts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is because in your example "an attempt" is actually acting as an adjective (it's describing the speech).  That's why it doesn't work when you put "try" in its place.  "Try" can't be used as an adjective.  Regarding the idiomatic "give it another try, the comparable version using "attempt" would be "to make another attempt".

Comment: This is just wrong, sorry—"an attempt" is predicative here but I don't know of any reasonable definition of "adjective" that would include it.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a use of *try* that would allow "It was a try at ...", but it's informal, and being informal some people will not use it, and few would use it of a speech that aimed "to pacify all parties concerned". Informal uses tend to be less universal than formal uses, as different people make different choices as to which informal uses are "incorrect" and this creates localised variations in use.

You can find examples by looking [here](https://www.google.ie/search?q=%22was%20a%20try%20at%22) and then excluding those which are using *try* in the rugby sense of the word.

The use of *try* that doesn't state what was tried, but implies it from context, is also less formal, but more commonly used, and hence less strange to your ears.

Conversely, the informal *stab* is the opposite:

> I made another stab at it.
>
> *I made another stab.

Ultimately, this just comes down to the definition of the words, in different registers and dialects. The definitions of *stab* include one where it means an attempt at something referred to, but does not include one where it means an attempt at something implied. The definitions of try include an attempt at something implied, but in many versions of English do not include an attempt at something referred to.

Answer (score 2):

The word *an attempt* has connotations of difficulty, whereas *a try* does not, simply!

> the ​act of ​trying to do something, ​especially something ​difficult:
>   [+ to infinitive]
>
> *She made a few ​half-hearted **attempts** to ​join in ​their ​conversation.*
>
> *He made no **attempt** to be ​sociable.*
>
> *This is my second **attempt** at the ​exam.*
>
> *None of ​our **attempts** at ​contacting Dr James was ​successful.*
>
> *They ​closed the ​road in an **attempt** (= to ​try to) to ​reduce ​traffic in the ​city.*

[definition of ***attempt*** and example sentences on Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/attempt)

The structures are *an attempt at something* and *an attempt to do something*… the preposition *at* is not used when *attempt* is followed by another verb, in the full infinitive.

> [C usually singular] an ​attempt to do something:
>
> *They might still have ​tickets ​left - why don't you give it a **try**?*
>
> *This will be her third **try** at ​jumping the ​bar.*
>
> *You could ​ask him if he's ​willing - it's ​worth a **try**.*

[definition of ***try*** and example sentences on Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/try)

The structures are *a try at something* and *a try at doing something*… the preposition *at* remains, and that's why the following verb is in the gerund.

Using *try* does not mean that the thing attempted is not difficult but simply that the idea is not especially present in the speaker's mind, whereas it is when they use *attempt*.

The definition of *try* tells you the noun is usually singular, so **if you want a plural, you will tend to use *attempt* instead, which is not illogical —come to think of it— since if the first try is not successful, then the thing attempted must have some difficulty in it, and the failure makes you aware of it**, hence *attempt* and no longer *try*.

I ngram-viewer-ed *several tries* and *several attempts*: *several attempts* appears to be more common.

[ngram viewer for the noun phrases *several tries* and *several attempts*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=several%20tries%2Cseveral%20attempts&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseveral%20tries%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseveral%20attempts%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

I can better say that *attempt* is more formal than *try*.

*Attempt* needs an object while *try* doesn't.

Examples:

> - ("Try!" – "I'm trying!" – "Attempt it!" – "I'm attempting it!")
> - "Try the tuna." means "Taste the tuna."
> - "Attempt the tuna." means "Try to perform some action called 'the tuna'."

Answer (score -1):

I'd not really say *I will give it another attempt*, which sounds a bit unidiomatic to my ears. That said, I don't think *a try* is wrong. You can say *I will give the idea a try.* Which is something perfectly normal.

Comment: *give it another* is informal; *attempt* is formal. That's why they sound strange together.